# Inequality from Analytic Number Theory

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to prove the following inequality from Analytic Number Theory which arises in the study of partial sums of a Dirichlet series:

$|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{b-iT}^{b+iT}\frac{a^{s}}{s}ds|\leq \frac{8}{7}a^{b}$ where $a>0, b>1, T>0$.

My attempt:

$|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{b-iT}^{b+iT}\frac{a^{s}}{s}ds|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-T}^{T}\frac{a^{b}dt}{\sqrt{b^{2}+t^{2}}}\leq \frac{a^{b}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{T}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}$,

There is a hint for this problem on applying the second mean value theorem, I tried to solve this problem by this theorem, but I can not reach the desired upper bound.
I also applied the rsidue theorem for contour with vertices $b+iT, iT, -iT, b-iT$ which doesn't contain the pole $s=0$ as an interior point, but I couldn't reach that upper bound.

Please help to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you use the residue theorem and transform the integral into pieces that can be estimated  absolutely  (what you did gives a divergent integral in $T$ so you won't  get any estimate independent  of $T$) but to use the hint you have to write $s=b+it$ substitute and split into real and imaginary  parts and apply the second mean value theorem with the monotone function $a^x$ and what remains is essentially $a^{it}/(b+it)$ which is easily estimated by parts

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I wrote the integral Cauchy theorem for rectangular countor with vertices $b+it, u+it, u-it, b-it$ such that singular point (s=0) is out of this countor, and I applied the second mean value theorem, but the upper bound is dependent to T. Is it possible to write your idea with more details? Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know, if there is a reference including solution for this problem.